# Flask request.args.get get all params (Python)

Tags: python, flask, get

how i can parse all GET params from URL in flask? 
I tried use **request.args.get**, but it works with specific GET params (pre defined), but i need parse it all from my large URL (ex: http://site.ru/?a=1&b=2&c=3&some_string=string...)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use `request.args` it will provide a dictonary with key-value pairs of the GET parameters

Ex: `http://website.com/index?arg1=hello&arg2=world`

```
print request.args
>> {"arg1": "hello", "arg2": "world"}
```

The `request.args.get(key)` is a useful dictionary function that will return `None` if the parameter is not set rather than raising a `KeyError`

Answer (score 4):

```
[i for i in request.args.keys()]
```